# Removing unnecessary zeros in a simple calculator app

Tags: ios, xcode, calculator

I made a simple calculator and Everytime I hit calculate it'll give a an answer but gives six unnecessary zeros, my question, how can I remove those zeros?

```
NSString *firstString = textfieldone.text;
NSString *secondString = textfieldtwo.text;

NSString *LEGAL = @"0123456789";
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:LEGAL] invertedSet];
NSString *filteredOne = [[firstString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                         componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *filteredTwo = [[secondString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] 
                         componentsJoinedByString:@""];
firstString = filteredOne;
secondString = filteredTwo;

//Here we are creating three doubles
double num1;
double num2;
double output;
//Here we are assigning the values 
num1 = [firstString doubleValue];
num2 = [secondString doubleValue];

output = num1 + num2;

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",output];
```

Example:

15 + 15 = 30.000000

Comment: Use NSDecimalNumber, which doesn't have those precision errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're displaying this by using a string, check the following approaches.

**NSString**

```
NSString * display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", number];
//This approach will return 30.0000000

NSString * display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", number];
//While this approach will return 30.00
```

**Note:** *You can specify the number of decimals you want to return by adding a point and a number before the 'f'*

### **-Edited-**

In your case use the following approach:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", output];
//This will display your result with 0 decimal places, thus giving you '30'
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that none of that is necessary if you use the `%g` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out. This should suit your requirements completely.

```
NSString * String1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",output];
NSArray *arrayString = [String1 componentsSeperatedByString:@"."];

float decimalpart = 0.0f;
if([arrayString  count]>1)
{
   decimalpart =  [[arrayString objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
}

//This will check if the decimal part is 00 like in case of 30.0000, only in that case it would strip values after decimal point. So output will be 30
if(decimalpart == 0.0f)
{
   label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", output];
}
else if(decimalpart > 0.0f) //This will check if the decimal part is 00 like in case of 30.123456, only in that case it would shows values upto 2 digits after decimal point. So output will be 30.12
{
   label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",output];
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps you.